# PHP equality - where am I going wrong?

Tags: php, integer, equality

This is driving me nuts. Two integers should be equal.

```
<?php

function getPort() {
    return 443;
}

$port = getPort(); 
var_dump(433, $port, $port == 433, 443 == $port, 433 == 433);

?>
```

Result in both PHP 5.2 and 5.4:

```
int(433)
int(443)
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

In the previous code why does $port not equal 443 but 443 *does* equals $port? I must be doing something stupid surely?

Comment: 443 and 433 ..optical illusion.

Comment: that's how it starts...love it :)

Comment: why the third one comes false?

Comment: @Basith Because 443 !== 433. :)

Comment: @Basith Because $port is 443, not 433.

Comment: @ GolezTrol --> Ya i am confusing little bit...

Comment: Thanks for the second pair of eyes. Literally was stuck on that for ages. Embarrassing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your doing $port == 433 in the first parameter and 443 in the second, and therefore it is correct.

So, to answer your question, yes; you are doing something stupid! ;)

Answer (score 4):

Small typo:

once you compare 433 with `$port` and not 443!

```
$port == 433
```

vs

```
443 == $port
```

Comment: because 433 == 433 and 443 != 433

Comment: @Fluffeh because `433 == 433` is true? or you mean the third one? In that case `$port` is set to 443, which equals 443 as in the comparison.

Comment: @MattHumphrey Yeah, got caught up with 443 :( Deleted question-Comment. +1'ed both answers.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting 443 in $port and comparing with 433.
This will always return false.